# Why do some integer modulos have no inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Integers modulo 7 follow the inverse property of multiplication, but integers modulo 9 do not; is there a reason why?

Comment: $7$ is prime, $9$ isn't.  Worth noting, that even modulo a composite you  get inverses if you stick to integers which are relatively prime to the modulus.  Thus, for instance, $2\times 5 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$.

Comment: Also notice that $ax + by = 1$ has no solution when $\gcd(a,b)\ne 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a prime number $p$ for your modulo,then you always get an inverse for $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$. And then this set is called finite field, meaning on this set addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are defined.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field

However, if you do not have a prime, then there are always elements without the inverse. I guess you are asking why this is.

For that, the reason is well written here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse
Only prime numbers are relatively prime with all the numbers smaller than the original prime.